# Removing seconds from :human-date in mu4e

Tags: mu4e

In mu4e, :human-date shows seconds which I would like to avoid? How can I only show hour and minute in the HH:MM format?

Answer (score 4):

You can customize `mu4e-headers-time-format` and `mu4e-headers-date-format`. 
Their default is to use a locale-dependant format (`"%X"` and `"%x"`), so I guess this should do the trick for you :

`(setq mu4e-headers-time-format "%H:%M")`